# Доступ к нестатическим методам класса в VC++ 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Насколько "криминальным" является такой доступ к нестатическим методам класса? Делал в Visual studio 2019 Community, с дефолтными настройками. Переносимость на другие платформы не важна, важно, чтобы это работало в дальнейших версиях Visual C++

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int val;
    Base():val(0) {}

    virtual int Func1(int newval)
    {
        val = newval;
        return val;
    }
};

class Child : public Base{
public:
    virtual int Func2(int newval)
    {
        val = newval*newval;
        return val;
    }

    virtual int Func1(int newval)
    {
        val = newval * 2;
        return val;
    }

    Child() : Base() {}

};

class Child2 : public Child
{
private:
    virtual int Func2(int newval)
    {
        val = newval * newval * newval;
        return val;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Base base;
    Child child;
    Child2 child2;

    int (Base::*func)(int) = &Base::Func1;
    int (Base::*func2)(int) = reinterpret_cast<int (Base::*)(int)>(&Child::Func2);

    Base* t = &base;

    (t->*func)(3);
    std::cout << "base::val=" << base.val << "\n";

    t = &child;
    (t->*func)(3);
    std::cout << "child::val=" << child.val << "\n";
    (t->*func2)(3);
    std::cout << "child::val=" << child.val << "\n";

    t = &child2;
    (t->*func)(3);
    std::cout << "child2::val=" << child2.val << "\n";
    (t->*func2)(3);
    std::cout << "child2::val=" << child2.val << "\n";

    getchar();
}
```

Выводит следующее:

```
base::val=3
child::val=6
child::val=9
child2::val=6
child2::val=27
```

Пробовал и релиз и дебаг и х86 и х64 - везде результат одинаков, ошибок не выдается.

Comment: Этот код не работает и в текущей версии. Дело в том, что в случае доступа через такой указатель, как и во многих других случаях Неопределенного Поведения, компилятор может и не выдавать ошибок, а программа может и не падать. Если вам хочется добиться именно явного падения - добавьте в классы каких-нибудь нетривиальных полей, хотя бы тот же `std::string`,

Comment: Пробовал std::string добавлять и в базовый класс и потомкам - все работает.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` - всегда будет приниматься. А `static_cast` - сейчас работает, пользуйтесь им. Он хотя-бы смотрит, что можно конвертировать, что нет.

Comment: Я понимаю (ну, надеюсь, что понимаю), что такое reinterpret_cast и static_cast. Вопрос не в этом. Вопрос в том, что я обращаюсь к виртуальным нестатическим методам класса через указатель и оно работает. Вопрос в том, что будет ли оно работать и дальше? Кстати, проверил в VS2015 - так же все работает.

Comment: @VTT: Какое именно Неопределенное Поведение вы имеет в виду в данном случае? Ошибкой здесь является только использование `reinterpret_cast` вместо `static_cast`. Во всех остальных отношениях поведение этого кода полностью определено. Логично ожидать если у автора этот код все таки "сработал" с `reinterpret_cast`, то он будет продолжать "работать" и после добавления в классы дополнительных полей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде все было бы абсолютно легально, если бы не неуместное использование `reinterpret_cast`.

Это контравариантное преобразование типов (преобразование указателя на член класса в направлении от потомка к предку) поддерживается в С++. Но делается оно через `static_cast`

```
int (Base::*func2)(int) = static_cast<int (Base::*)(int)>(&Child::Func2);
```

Обратите внимание, что даже несмотря на то, что в классе `Base` нет метода `Func2`, это преобразование является *полностью легальным и определенным*. Язык С++ требует наличия соответствующего метода `Func2` в динамическом типе объекта только *в момент вызова* через такой указатель. В момент выполнения преобразования и инициализации указателя таких требований не накладывается.

То есть если бы далее вдруг сделали

```
Base* t = &base;
(t->*func2)(3);  // UB
```

то вы бы наткнулись на неопределенное поведение при вызове. Но в вашем коде таких нарушений нет.

Из-за неуместного использования `reinterpret_cast` вместо `static_cast` ваш код имеет неопределенное поведение. В остальном никаких проблем в коде нет. Да, окончательное разрешение вызовов *виртуальных* методов класса через указатель в С++ делается *в момент вызова*. То есть все должно работать именно так, как оно работает в вашем примере.

Замените `reinterpret_cast` на `static_cast` и вы получите корректный код с полностью определенным спецификацией языка С++ поведением. Никакой "завязки на компилятор" в этом коде нет. Скорее наоборот, именно в VS для того, чтобы заставить аналогичный код корректно работать в более сложных случаях (множественное наследование, виртуальное наследование) вам придется повозиться с `#pragma pointers_to_members`. В других компиляторах все будет работать сразу.